# How use customer hash function for user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my user model I have

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.string "password_digest"
end
```

I don't understand how `t.string "password_digest"` work in rails?
Will it use a default hash function?

Comment: You will mostly use that with bcrypt gem read this - https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: Suggest you use devise https://github.com/heartcombo/devise for your authentication needs, or at least look at it to understand how it works -- hint -- it's not an easy problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will not automatically do anything with your column just because its named `password_digest`. You actually have to implement password encryption for anything to happen.

Rails introduced [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) in 3.1 to create a standardized way to handle password encryption and avoid the pitfalls of reinventing the password encryption wheel.

```
# make sure you add bcrypt to the gemfile and run bundle install
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end
```

It adds a `password=` setter on the model which hashes the password with [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and sets the `password_digest`. It also adds a `password_confirmation=` setter and validations.

You can then authenticate users by calling:

```
class SessionsController
  def create
    # will be nil or false if the email or password does not check out
    @user = User.find_by(params[:email])&.authenticate(params[:password])
    if @user
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/somewhere'
    else
      render :new, notice: 'Invalid email or password'
    end
  end
end
```

This compares the result of hashing `params[:password]` to the values stored in the database. Of course you should not really reinvent the authentication wheel if you don't want to learn more about wheels. For production apps you should really choose battle tested solutions like Devise.